# Meaning of NSOpenGLPFAColorSize for NSOpenGLPixelFormat

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, opengl

I'm unclear as to what value to set for NSOpenGLPFAColorSize when creating an NSOpenGLPixelFormat. From the documentation it states:

> Value is a nonnegative buffer size specification. A color buffer that most closely matches the specified size is preferred. If unspecified, OpenGL chooses a color size that matches the screen.

But does this mean the number of bits per pixel? Or bits per component? For example, if it were set 24 and interpreted as **bits per pixel** then that would mean that each RGBA color would have 6-bits per component for a total of 24-bits for the entire RGBA pixel.

However, if it is to be interpreted as **bits per component** then that would mean 24-bits for each of the red, green, blue and alpha components to make a 96-bit RGBA pixel.

I'm inclined to believe that it means **bits per component** as the values I've seen set in sample code ranges from 8, 16, 24, 32 <s>and everything but 24 makes sense when interpreted as **bits per component**.</s> It would be nice though to have some definitive answer.

**Note:** Edited to reflect that pixels in OpenGL are RGBA not RGB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After scouring the documentation further I came across the `NSOpenGLPFAColorFloat` attribute, which according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenGLPixelFormat_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSOpenGLPFAColorFloat):

> A Boolean attribute. If present, this attribute indicates that only renderers that are capable using buffers storing floating point pixels are considered. This should be accompanied by a NSOpenGLPFAColorSize of 64 (for half float pixel components) or 128 (for full float pixel components). Note, not all hardware supports floating point color buffers thus the returned pixel format could be NULL.

With that additional information it must mean **bits per pixel**.

I did some experimenting as well, setting `NSOpenGLPFAColorSize` to each of 8, 16, 24 & 32 and then checking what I got back. In each case I was returned a pixel format with `NSOpenGLPFAColorSize` set to 32 - meaning 32-bits per RGBA pixel. Just passing `NSOpenGLPFAColorFloat` with nothing set for the Color Size is enough to get back a pixel format with 64-bits per pixel.